# Using references while setting a pair in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using a loop to create a "lookup" table and as you know, in PHP and many other languages you can use the reference operator to reference the array. But if I'm setting an array in another array, I can't seem to do this in 1 line.

Right now my code is:

```
$results[++$count] = array();
$array = &$results[$count];
```

Is there a way I can makes something like this work:

```
$array = &$results[++$count] = array();
```

**Edit:** I've tested this and still no luck (I assumed it wouldn't work but it was worth a shot)

```
$array = &($results[++$count] = array());
```

Comment: i don't think you can create a reference before the item is instantiated so therefore I don't think you can do it on one line, except as `$results[++$count] = array(); $array = &$results[$count];` :)

Comment: Thanks, I figured that it might be impossible but don't know much about PHP so I assumed there might be some way. Thanks again :)

Comment: Just to confirm - no, this isn't possible in PHP - you need to have a variable first before you can use the `&` operator.

Comment: Alright thanks. This wasn't necessarily for the line reduction (as I may have implied) but just to see how things work. I assumed it would have created the array and return it, then set a reference to it, but I was wrong :)